# require('fs') not working with angular and electron

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, electron, fs

I am using angular 6.0, electron 2.0, typescript 2.9, nodejs 9.11 to make a desktop app using electron framework.  I am struggling with accessing NodeJS native API from the typescript code. I have set "commonjs" in the "tsconfig.app.json" file. When I write : require('fs') or require('net') in any of the ts files which are part of angular application, the system isn't able to find those modules.

Only one solution has worked so far. It goes like this. First in 'native.js'

```
window.fs = require('fs')
```

Then in polyfill.ts :

```
declare global {
  interface Window{
    fs : any;
  }
}
```

Then access `fs` in the rest of codebase as `window.fs`.

While this is okay, but it is not scalable as if I have to use any library which depends on NodeJS native API, then that library has to be imported through this mechanism.

Is there any other solution to let angular allow importing of nodejs system libraries through normal `require(<module>)` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as Fs from 'fs';
const fs: typeof Fs = window['require']('fs');
```

Answer (score 0):

on my side, this work if you use typescript for ref.
You need give a defenition or is will any.
Using this for nwjs, know nodejs is global.

`const fs: typeof import('fs') = require('fs');`

---

[image]